# How to use Fixtures in Comfortable Mexican Sofa

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I set the config options to enable fixtures as explained in the [man page](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki/Working-with-CMS-fixtures)

I then made a layoutTest.html in various places (file folders, not in the front-end cms) including the db folder and I could not get it to show up as a layout in the CMS back-end.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you created a page, exported it to fixtures and then imported it but it doesn't show up?

Comment: @CharlieEgan I was thinking the import was optional, in that CMS would auto pull the files using a directory traversal and display them.  I guess editing the files in CMS's cms should be up for optionality if that were the case.  I see that there are options that must be set in the config so it really doesn't make to me that an import would be necessary if these options must have been set to do *something*.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @CharlieEgan If you look into config/initializers/[CMS].rb there is the setting config.enable_fixtures = true and config.fixtures_path = File.expand_path('db/cms_fixtures', Rails.root).  What reason would these be there other than pulling fixtures automatically? A terminal command would not need these options bc the command needs the folder path to the fixtures, which has been specified redundantly in the config.

Comment: When things don't work I suggest reverting to the point where you had default cms fixtures. Then make sure that `sample-site` folder matches identifier for the site. Then set `config.enable_fixtures` to `true` and restart server. Fixture data should be pulled in. Remember that fixture sync is destructive. It will delete stuff that's not defined in fixtures.

Comment: @Grocery I had already mimicked the folder structure, but I neglected to restart the server.  Thank You for the tip!  If you would like, post an official answer and I will accept it.

Comment: crazy - having the same problem as original poster, but can't get it to work. server restart, renaming, dropping database tables and recreating … all to no end: CMS loads the fixtures once, and never again.

Comment: @danieldekay Not to derail the topic, but I switched to Scala and Play ;).  If you need help just ask a new question and you can link this one in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mimicked the folder structure in /db/sample-site with my site slug in place of sample-site.

Key point is to restart the Rails server, as the config settings are read only after that is done.

From there on simply refreshing the page will load the new layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Based on feedback from comments on question:

fixtures_path is only for specifying where you want fixtures to be located. You still need to import and export fixtures using the commands to make use of them.

Comment: If using the command to import will copy the files from the folder specified in the command to the DB then what is the point of the config options?

Comment: I don't have a Comfy project at the moment but I'd guess it's just a default.

Comment: You don't need rake task to import. Importing should happen automatically if you have `config.enable_fixtures` set to `true`

Comment: @Grocery that is exactly what I would expect.  Do you know what folder in /db/ I should be dropping the layout fixture in?  I think I tried everything possible.

Comment: @BAR when you run `rails g comfy:cms` it creates a `db/cms_fixtures/sample-site` folder that has example fixtures. All you have to do mimic how it's structured. `sample-site` folder name should match identifier of your cms site.